# How can I identify items in the real world?

Tags: augmented-reality

Theoretically, how can I take a picture of a room and identify items in the room?
Let's say we have a table and a book on the table. Is there any way to identify them?

Comment: An incredible amount of work has been done on this from the 1970s onwards. While a lot of partial solutions exist for different problem domains (From barcodes to ANPR to guiding cruise missiles to OCR to autonomous vehicles) this is a generic problem which humans are not too good at either. It's not really a programming question though, hence the downvote.

Comment: >this is a generic problem which humans are not too good at either - I think I object to that, humans are amazing at object recognition ;)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a book on this table sat next to a pile of papers which happen to be of the same dimensions?
Or perhaps a larger encyclopedia? Define a book to a computer.

This is an incredibly difficult problem and certainly not something simple to answer. Where I am based there is extensive research going on into identifying things on a typical road - which is incredibly difficult.

Personally I would have a look into the Kinect SDK that Microsoft intend to release in the summer, I have no doubt people will try to use this to help develop some more frameworks, but remember that part of the problem is going to be differentiating between different items of the same dimensions. Non trivial.

Edits: Making sure it looks like I know how to type :P

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching with many different samples of the objects from all possible angles. The more images you have to analyse regions and shape the better your results will be.

Comment: @Amborsia First off all, thank you.
Is there any framework that works with images (in order to compare items)? And once I have a picture should I compare it to patterns in the database?

Answer (score 0):

one could use SIFT-Features if the items are known, have a look here: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/

Answer (score 0):

See [this project](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~qp202/my_papers/BMVC09/) (especially the YouTube video) on how depth information (and therefore object separation) can be achieved with a video source.

It would be incredibly hard with a single picture due to there being little depth information. Binocular vision would add some depth information (i.e. a pair of images taken from two different angles but of the same scene). The above project uses the changes in the scene over time to calculate depth.

Comment: Interesting work. I took the interpretation of 'identify' in the question to mean that @Ron wanted the computer to recognize the items in the room as opposed to modelling them.

Comment: @Draineh: yes, I understood that too. The point of linking that project is that once an area is modelled in 3D, it is a much simpler proposition to identify the objects within it as you can more easily see where each begins and ends and what shape they are.